# Update cell value if new value is availiable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, collections

So I am brainstorming a few different ways to accomplish this task... but none of the ways I am thinking are very clean. I am looking for a clean way to accomplish this.

I have 2 workbooks (workbook A, workbook B).

Workbook A looks like this:

```
 A    B    C    D    E
Tom  Bob  Sam  Ted  Meg
 1    4    9    3    2
```

The A,B,C... are the columns (not actually on the sheet) and the 1,4,9,3,2 is data on the last row (could be row 10 or row 1000, etc...)

Workbook B looks like this:

```
  A    B
 Sam   5   
 Meg   1
```

I want to update workbook A with any values on workbook B. So... in this example... Sam and Meg has a new value... So I want to update workbook A to look like this:

```
 A    B    C    D    E
Tom  Bob  Sam  Ted  Meg
 1    4    5    3    1
```

I feel like the simplest way to do this may be to make something like a dictionary or something like that but I have never used a dictionary and don't know if some other method would be easier / simpler.

Comment: I forgot that you can implement a key value pair using a collection... similar to a dictionary... I have also never done this... I don't know if that would be an elegant solution...

Comment: Hi XCELLGUY, could you give us a little more info please, is the first workbook only getting updated from the second workbook? or are there other sources that will be changing the data? I assume you are talking about more than just a transpose of the same data? What do you to want to happen when the data in the 2nd workbook changes? do you want the just the last row to change or do you want a new row with updated values below it?

Comment: Of course this is a simplified example... but the key in this example is that I only have new data for sam and meg... so only sam and meg will get updated values... the other values will stay the same...

Comment: Wait... Can I use ".PasteSpecial" and "SkipBlanks:=True" and "Transpose:=True"... I have never used or known about the "SkipBlanks" option... I think I can make that work.

Comment: Yes... I think that's my simplest option. I can use a lookup function and then use ".PasteSpecial" and "SkipBlanks:=True" and "Transpose:=True"...

Comment: Why can't you just link the cells in workbook A to Workbook B? So, when ever the value gets updated in Workbook B the value in Workbook A gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, a little more background on my problem. I am opening text files, extracting data, re-arranging the data on an excel sheet (wkbTemp), and then copying the re-arranged data to "wkbCompiledDataTable."

Here is how i solved my problem.

```
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Activate
LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).row 

wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Range("J1:N" & LRow).Copy

wkbCompiledDataTable(1).Activate   
LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).row    

wkbCompiledDataTable(1).Sheets(1).Range("D" & LRow).PasteSpecial _
                                                          Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                          SkipBlanks:=True, _
                                                          Transpose:=True
```

As I said earlier, the actual application is much more complicated. This routine is actually in a loop. So for example I actually have "wkbCompiledDataTable(i)" instead of "wkbCompiledDataTable(1)." But for me this was the simplest solution. wkbTemp.Sheets(1) Column "J" has data. Column "K" is blank. Column "L", Column "M", Column "N" has data (These 3 columns are the columns I was concerned with data changing).

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to get data from one book to another then vlookup is the simplest solution

https://photos.app.goo.gl/CRjxhJHVKm6xKJ8x7

I nested it within an if statement that checks to see if there is an error, if there is an error then it just grabs the value from the line above. I.e. if the Name doesn't exist on your second sheet, then there is an error and it will just grab from the line above.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)),A11,VLOOKUP(A1,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE))
```

On the face value, this does what you are asking but the way you phrased the question implies that there is some other functionality and some other things you need to do that this solution will possibly get in the way of. That's why I was trying to clarify what you really want to achieve.

Anyway, hopefully its a step in the right direction... Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it. No dictionary, however going through memory in an array:

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

---

***<sub>Sample code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long, col As Long
Dim arr As Variant

'Step 1: Get the values to update
With Sheet1 
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:B" & lr)
End With

'Step 2: Go through our values to update
With Sheet2
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        col = .Rows(1).Find(arr(x, 1), Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row + 1, col) = arr(x, 2)
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

Remove the `+1` in case you want to rewrite the last entry in the found column. I just assumed you wanted to paste the value underneath. Also, I refered to sheets, you can simply refer to the other open workbook.

Comment: So i do not need the plus 1. But looks like this will work. Thank you.

Comment: @xcellguy. If this has answered your question please upvote/accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Doing so would return the favour in the form of exp points plus it would close the thread

Comment: On another note, I see you have loads of open questions. You might want to revisit those too and accept the answers given if they helped you out. Clicking the checkmark will accept the answer (closing the thread) and the arrows (also on the left of the answers) will upvote the answer as being helpful. It's only a decent thing to do. @xcellguy

Comment: @XCELLGUY, if this thread needs to be closed you need to start marking answer as being correct. Also see my last comment.